# Remove begining and end of string until it finds a pattern in R

Tags: r, regex, string, gsub

So I have a string representing a secondary structure of folding RNA such as:

```
"....(((((((((...((...(((((((((((..((.(.......))))))))..))))..)))....."
```

My objective is to get rid of these points in the extremes of the string, so that I get:

```
"(((((((((...((...(((((((((((..((.(.......))))))))..))))..)))"
```

I have been trying by using the gsub function like:

```
gsub("\\.+\\(", "", string)
```

for the begining, and:

```
gsub("\\)\\.+", "", string)
```

for the end

but the output of this command is:

```
"(((((((((((((((((((((((((.......))))))))..))))..)))....."
```

and:

```
"....(((((((((...((...(((((((((((..((.(.......)))))))))))))))"
```

Basically, I do not want the intermediate dots to be removed, just the ones at the begining and at the end.

Does anyone know a good way to solve it in R?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can either escape (`\\.`) or place the `.` in square brackets (`[.]`) as `.` is a metacharacter to match any character.

```
gsub("^[.]*|[.]*$", "", string)
#[1] "(((((((((...((...(((((((((((..((.(.......))))))))..))))..)))"
```

In the above, we specify the anchor (`^`) to match the start of the string followed by zero or more `.` (`*`) or `|`, zero or more dots at the end (`$`) of the string and replace with blank (`""`)

#### data

```
string <- "....(((((((((...((...(((((((((((..((.(.......))))))))..))))..)))....."
```

Answer (score 4):

In R 3.6.0 `trimws` has a `whitespace=` argument so using `x` in the Note at the end:

```
trimws(x, whitespace = "\\.")
## [1] "(((((((((...((...(((((((((((..((.(.......))))))))..))))..)))"
```

### Note

```
x <- "....(((((((((...((...(((((((((((..((.(.......))))))))..))))..)))....."
```